# delete data from database where date ... SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to delete some data from database:

```
WHERE created_at < NOW() - 30 min
```

How to wirte the 30 min into sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculate older date and compare with it:

```
WHERE created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
```

See [`DATE_ADD` description](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) for list of all available units.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;
```